# Has there ever been a live-action movie that takes place entirely underwater?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, film-location

Have there been any movies that take place entirely underwater?

It looks like it is a rare kind of film that takes place entirely underwater because all the water/underwater-themed movies I've seen have above-the-surface scenes. I've tried watching the trailer of the movies I haven't seen and they also had above-the-surface scenes.

Specifically, I wonder if there ever was a fictional feature film that is set entirely underwater:

- a feature film
- no above-the-surface scene
- not a documentary
- not an animation movie

If there are various ones indeed, it would certainly be interesting which was the first movie to do so, but it doesn't seem like this is a common thing to begin with and I'd be first and foremost concerned to know if there are any at all.

All the movies that come to my mind have scenes above the surface (like *The Abyss*) or start/end above the surface. There might be an Atlantis themed movie that takes place entirely underwater. I've found the Wikipedia lists below but I haven't watched all these movies obviously. Someone might remember a movie from these lists:

[**Underwater action films**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Underwater_action_films) 
[**Films set in Atlantis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_set_in_Atlantis)

If the only answer is an animation movie; some movies that come to mind are *Finding Nemo, The Little Mermaid, Shark Tale, Ponyo*... but I think they all have surface scenes (maybe except *Shark Tale*? I didn't watch the whole movie).

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm that *Shark Tale* is set entirely underwater.

Comment: Does this include submarines?  There is a whole list of potential submarine movies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_films

Comment: @rtaft: I didn't think about it but most might have above-the-surface scenes.

Comment: Related meta discussion: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637/49

Comment: "The Abyss" comes 'oh so close.'

Comment: Does finding Nemo count.. They are underwater in every scene, granted that they are underwater in an aquarium in some scenes but you never said ocean!

Comment: Sphere comes reasonably close but doesn't fully match. The only above water scenes are the initial arrival scene which is not plot-relevant, and the final scene whose location didn't need to be above water specifically.

Comment: Finding Nemo doesn't count, because of the dentist scene.  And the seagull scenes. 
 :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *[Underwater](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5774060/)* actually takes place entirely underwater, but they're inside a building and pods inside the water, so I don't know if that counts.

Comment: I've finally watched this movie. I can confirm that it takes place entirely underwater as the name of the movie suggests. However, if I would be nitpicky, there are some photos shown at the end of the movie which show above the surface scenes. I don't know if we can consider photos shown in a movie as a scene? I will accept this till a better one comes up. It was a good movie nevertheless.